# phpQuery finding the type of tag

Tags: phpquery

I need to be able to determine the type of tag i have selected with phpQuery.

So, if i have the reference of an element, how can i easily figure out its tag type?

In jquery/js tagName will suffice or prop('tagName')

But in phpQuery i cannot seem to find a straight forward function to do this..

```
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentFilePHP($ftp_file['local_path']);
if(!pq('.clasToFind')->length) {
      $tagType = pq('.clasToFind')->tagName;
}
```

Is the best answer regex the answer here?

Comment: Sometimes questions are short. The above question can be extremely short.. however I was forced to extend the word count to pass the 'quality test'.. is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tagName is a DomNode property. So when you iterate:

```
foreach(pq('.clasToFind') as $el){
  echo $el->tagName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here: [How to find tag name using phpquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645478/how-to-find-tag-name-using-phpquery/40096122#40096122)

You need to call `get` to point to the first element of the collection, even if it has only one element. So, your code would be something like this:

```
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentFilePHP($ftp_file['local_path']);
if($doc->find('.clasToFind')->length) {
      $tagType = $doc->find('.clasToFind')->get(0)->tagName;
}
```