# How to find tag name using phpquery?

Tags: php, jquery, dom, phpquery

I am using phpquery to extract some data from a webpage. I need to identify the menu of the page. My implementation is to find each element that has sibilings > 0 and last-child is an `"a"`. My code is:

```
foreach($this->doc['*'] as $tagObj){
$tag = pq($tagObj);
if(count($tag->siblings()) > 0){
    if($tag->find(":last-child")->tagName  === "a")
        echo trim(strip_tags($tag->html())) . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

However, I am not getting any output because of

> $tag->find(":last-child")->tagName

which isn't returning anything. What would be the reason for this?

Comment: Does the pq object have the methods find and sibling?  I don't think so.. maybe

Comment: it does have it - https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Traversing

Comment: What does the html structure look like at that point? Could it just be that for some reason there aren't any items with siblings and children?

Comment: What do you get if you make a var_dump of $tag->find(":last-child") ? Is it the one you searched for? Make a Testcase whisch should return that. Consider to use :last.

_btw the menu or nav? caus' nav is nav and menu is a <ul>/<ol> with <li> in it with <a> in it. no need to check if the **last** one is <a>_

Answer (score 4):

I don't know this library but perhaps something like this

```
$siblings = $tag->siblings();
if (($siblingCount = count($siblings)) && $siblings[$siblingCount - 1]->tagName === 'a') {
    echo ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should use **:last** instead of **:last-child**

According to the [library Google Page](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/):

```
$li = null;
$doc['ul > li']
        ->addClass('my-new-class')
        ->filter(':last') // <--- :last
                ->addClass('last-li')
// save it anywhere in the chain
                ->toReference($li);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in reverse check for `a:last-child` :

For example :

```
foreach($this->doc['*'] as $tagObj){
$tag = pq($tagObj);
if(count($tag->siblings()) > 0){
    if($tag->find("a:last-child"))
        echo trim(strip_tags($tag->html())) . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

This will check for the `a` tag of `last-child` and you can get its content easily.
May this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Because `phpQueryObject` returned by `pq` implements the `Iterator` and uses a public array `$elements` to store all elements, we need to get the element using the `get()` function, which returns a `DOMElement` that is has the `tagName` and `nodeName` properties:

```
$q = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML('<div><span class="test-span">Testing test</span></div>');
echo $q->find('.test-span')->get(0)->tagName; // outputs "span"
//echo $q->find('.test-span')->get(0)->nodeName; // outputs "span"
```

Both properties will output the tag name that has the `test-span` class which of course is `span`.